# How to make multi-tenancy in pentaho BI 8.0?

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

I want to create a multi-tenancy in Pentaho 8.0, so I can keep my clients reports stored dynamically in their databases (without hardcoding). But I don't have any ideas of where are the directory and the `.xml` file that are in the [documentation](https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/8.0/Developer_Center/Multi-Tenancy):

> webapps/pentaho/WEB-INF/lib 
>   pentahoObjects.spring.xml

My best guess is that this is just available for those who have the Pentaho installed as an executable, and I only have the .zip file downloaded [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pentaho/files/Business%20Intelligence%20Server/). But, with the research that I did, I found the directory above in some older Pentaho versions (such as 5.1). Maybe they've changed the directory and the file names. I have no idea.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Pentaho 7.0](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pentaho/files/Business%20Intelligence%20Server/7.0/) / [Pentaho 8.0](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pentaho/files/Pentaho%208.0/server/)

- `pentaho-server/tomcat/webapps/pentaho/WEB-INF/lib`
- `pentaho-server/pentaho-solutions/system/pentahoObjects.spring.xml`